# What is $P$(two distinct users with poor MSE etiquette)?

Tags: discussion

[Lucero](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29364/lucero-hernandez-sanchez) and [Miguel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29282/miguel-mora-luna)

These guys ask similar questions...

Can we investigate? Does it matter?

Comment: I thought there was a "No Names" policy on meta. You should have contacted the moderators somehow.

Comment: @Asaf: Link? ${}{}$

Comment: It appears mostly in comments to threads like this one. I guess "policy" was the wrong word, but it is always best to avoid pointing fingers at specific users when it sounds as though you are accusing someone of something (like here).

Comment: Apparently your suggestion that I accuse anonymous users is popular with the meta-dwellers!

Comment: I never said that you were accusing anyone. If you take a moment to read your post it can be read as hinting that at least one of these users is a sock puppet. I would refrain from pointing out the users and asking what to do in the general case, or write to the moderators directly instead.

Comment: @Asaf: That's reasonable. I thought it was clear that I *was* making an accusation! (I was)

Comment: I knew that you were making an accusation, but I did not want to make an accusation myself in case I was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lucero and I are college friends and invite her to enter this site since we left school in 120 probability and statistics problems on Tuesday for Friday, reason why we use this site to solve a twenty-we would do the rest of us, thank you for your attention

Comment: Thanks for speaking up, Miguel. Maybe you would care to address the issues that others have raised with your (and your friend's) questions: no work shown, no interaction with commenters, answerers, and no (little?) use of the homework tag.

Comment: Please show some work; please add the homework tag if they are homework problems. Further, your answer is not at all clear to me. What do you mean when you say `since we left school in 120 probability and statistics problems on Tuesday for Friday, reason why we use this site to solve a twenty-we would do the rest of us` -- Would you please care to expand on the quote?

Comment: @Kannappan: "we left" is probably "we were left" or "we were given"; I'm guessing a literal translation of *nos dejaron* or *nos dieron* from the Spanish...

Comment: @Miguel: Feel free to edit your answer and supply an equivalent one in your native tongue if you feel more comfortable. Someone is bound to quickly supply a translation. Cheers.