# mysterious closing of a question

Tags: discussion, closing, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133670/continuous-distribution-function/133681#133681) was "closed as too localized by cardinal, Benjamin Lim, The Chaz, did, Zev Chonoles" on May 8th.  A statement below it said:

> "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

None of that makes the least bit of sense at all.  To say it applies only to a certain geographic area is lunacy.  It's a perfectly reasonable question.  And the answer explains why the null distributions of certain p-values in hypothesis tests are what they are.

Why did this happen?

**Later edit:** Once again I find people saying that a poster is in the habit of posting bad stuff; therefore when the poster posts something good it should be down-voted and closed, and a false statement of why it was closed should be published.

That is wrong.

Comment: Good question. I will ask around.

Comment: -1 for "lunacy"

Comment: "To say it applies only to a certain geographic area is lunacy."  It may be, but nobody did say or imply that, even if we were to take the closing description seriously.  There is a logical disjunction combining three possible descriptions.  In particular, "extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet," is vague and subjective enough that the users who voted might have believed it applies.

Comment: I voted to close, roughly for the reasons hypothesized by Michael Greinecker below. (Here is an exercise for the readers with a statistical bend: enumerate the pieces of feedback ignored by the OP in this closed question and in his others, and decide whether the closed one is worse in this respect than the average of the others, or not.) I do not remember whether I chose the *too localized* motivation or another one.

Comment: Two side remarks. (a.) -1 for "lunacy" in the present post. (b.) The *p-value* sentence is rather odd as well. I think I know what p-values and null *hypothesis* are... but I am not sure these are visible in the answer at all, and I am pretty sure they were lost on this OP anyway.

Comment: I am greatly saddened by the behavior exhibited by a handful of folks here, who have closed [6 or 7 of the users questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/29282/miguel-mora-luna?tab=questions&sort=newest) over a day and a half (April 18), during which two users cast 6 close votes each, and another two cast 4 votes each. Possibly this was organized on the chat forum (where they actively organize so-called "firing squads" to close posts). Surely there were many more *constructive* options available. Some of these posts should probably be reopened.

Comment: Some people object to the word "lunacy".  Why is it wrong to say that the notion that things like $1+1=2$ holds only in some geographic regions is lunacy?  @did : p-values were nowhere explicitly mentioned in the question or the answer, but it's hardly improbable that people who read the question and the answer will later encounter the application to p-values.

Comment: I am being subjected to cowardly bullying.  Some people are putting on airs and pretending to be offended by the word "lunacy", which I used to describe their offensive sarcasm, while they go out of their way to be boors and bullies.

Comment: +1 for bringing it up.

Comment: @Bill I think it would be constructive if you would point out the constructive ways to proceed.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Who is "subjecting you to cowardly bullying"?! Whose "offensive sarcasm" have you described? Who is "putting on airs and pretending to be offended"?

Comment: @cardinal In a forum as diverse as this there is bound to be widely varying opinions on such subjective matters. Please don't take such disagreements too personally. It would be difficult if not impossible to find two users who always agree on such matters.

Comment: @Bill: I am ***greatly*** saddened that a moderator has taken it upon himself to make such an ill-informed and entirely *false* comment such as your first one in this thread. In the process, several *conscientious*, *caring*, *devoted* (and high-reputation) users have been needlessly, improperly and *incorrectly* maligned. If you have some *constructive* comments to make about the so-called "firing squads" you reference (of which this is the first I have heard of such a thing), please *open a meta thread about it*. It is *off topic* here and entirely irrelevant to the rest of your comment.

Comment: @Bill: We can continue this in chat at another time, if you'd like. What I object to is the contrived notion you are displaying that you somehow believe you can judge *post hoc* the actions of several very respected members of this community *four months* after those actions were taken. In this instance, it shows a lack of appropriate humility and introspection and, to those actually aware of that situation, it is shocking in how far off-base it is. Seriously. Sincere regards.

Comment: @cardinal My comment is not off-topic since some (but not all) of said close-voters do participate in said chat "firing squads". I never said that you did. And even if it wasn't the result of such a chat firing squad, I *still* think there are more constructive ways to proceed. If you should ever wish to continue to discuss these matters *constructively* then I will be happy to join you. But, alas, I find your penultimate comment extremely nonconstructive and not conducive to further discussion. Goodbye.

Comment: Dear @Bill: In a forum as diverse as this there is bound to be widely varying opinions on such subjective matters. Please don't take such disagreements too personally. It would be difficult if not impossible to find two users who always agree on such matters. I will ping you at a later time to set up a private chat. Regards.

Comment: I find it odd how you have difficulty seeing how you (1) reference a particular situation, (2) follow it with a specific accusation (*Probably, this was...*) and then (3) in your last comment suggest that you were not intimating that those participating in the closure were doing that. It also does not comport with the stance you've taken with others that situations be addressed in the abstract. But, the signal-to-noise ratio is dropping again, so this is all I will say here.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker : Pretending to find it offensive that I found it lunacy to say that mathematics applies only in some geographic locales is what I called offensive sarcasm.  Some people say they are offended by that; one person above down-voted my question because of it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Two person stated that they voted you down for it, did and I. I don't see anybody who statet that they were offended.   Try to be a bit more honest.

Comment: @MichaelHardy As proclaimed by the German weekly *Focus*, we need *Fakten, Fakten, Fakten* here. Are you indeed *being subjected to cowardly bullying*? Where? By whom? How? On this page, I see nothing of the sort but surely I am wrong. Enlighten me.

Comment: Bullying or whatever aside, I am still slightly bemused at the reaction to the word "lunacy". It wasn't that narrow a question, was it? Which is the point Michael Hardy was trying to convey...

Comment: I agree with Michael. Obviously this question was closed [ad hominem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem).

Comment: @JenniferDylan: "Obviously"? :-)

Comment: @JenniferDylan You have obviously not read your link: "An *ad hominem* (Latin for "to the man"), short for *argumentum ad hominem*, is an attempt to negate the truth of a claim by pointing out a negative characteristic or belief of the person supporting it." Voting to close is not negating the truth of any claim.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I used it as an **analogy** not in the literal sense! My point was that I think the question was deemed low quality *just because the OP is M. M. Luna* (which is why I used the term *ad hominem*), but not necessarily because the question is low quality on its own.

Comment: @Jennifer How about being closed for *both* reasons?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker May be these closures were in fact because the questions are low quality. Of course this is all guesses about the voters. I'm not accusing, I'm just pointing out that we shouldn't use closure as a penalizing mechanism. It's a judgement on the question quality not the OP's behaviour. (That's why I think the solution is allowing the community to vote on banning users & penalty boxes; it's now exclusive to moderators. But that's another topic.).

Comment: @Jennifer I totally agree.

Comment: Another important thing is that we should allow those who have behaved badly in the past to change their ways.  That means one should not down-vote or delete a _good_ question on the grounds that the poster has posted bad questions earlier.

Comment: Michael, I totally agree! I have an honest question, though: You are a well-trained statistician and I believe you have good intentions; why have you not spent a few minutes collecting some *data* here and analyzing it? I think you will find the OP's behavior has *not* changed appreciably despite many kind, patient attempts from a multitude of users to communicate with him. You will see that the closure of his questions is highly correlated in time with his submission of *clusters* of new questions. You will also find extremely strong evidence to dispute the claims made in Bill's comments.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: If it would be helpful, I can try to put together a response that draws on some of my own recollections of what has happened here and some other observations, though it has been several months and my memory is not what it once was. :-)

Comment: While I differ with @Bill with how such remarks are to be interpreted, there were several [calls](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4263545#4263545) to "executions" in chat on April 18. But I'm pretty sure such remarks should be read as suggestions to look at some question and close it in case one considers it closeworthy. There was no cabal conspiring to close all questions of some user or anything a like. All calls to executioners were for specific questions (I read the whole transcript of that day, most of the closed questions seem to be deleted by now).

Answer (score 13):

Apparently, people were fed up with the behavior of a poster who has been repeatedly told to show own work, tag correctly etc. Two persons in the comments posted a link to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/what-is-ptwo-distinct-users-with-poor-mse-etiquette) meta-thread. There is no category for closing questions for spamming-with-low-quality-questions-and -ignoring-all-feedback, so the question was closed for a different reason.

One can debate whether that is a valid use of voting to close, but I'm sure one shouldn't take the description as "too localized" literally.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? This seems to be a valid observation based not only on the comments on [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133670/continuous-distribution-function/), but also on the comments to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134141/a-question-on-the-composition-of-relations). Whether the closing of the question is good or bad, I don't see a reason to downvote this answer.

Comment: You say there is no category for closing questions for spamming with low-quality questions.  That makes no sense unless the question I asked about was a low-quality question or was spam.  But it was a good question.  You seem to say that that if people are fed up with someone for spamming with low-quality questions, then they should down-vote and close _good_ questions that the same person posts.  That is wrong.  This question I asked about was closed with a stated reason that is absurd, and when I ask why, you say it's because there's no category for spamming with.....

Comment: .....low-quality questions.  But this was neither spam nor a low-quality question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Please don't read something into my post which isn't there. It is descriptive, not normative. I'm still undecided what the best way to deal with certain behavior is. But I do think the question was low quality. It showed zero research effort and used the imperative mode.

Comment: It is standard practice on MO to close homework questions as "too localized". It does not seem absurd to close particularly bad homework questions here similarly, even if the description is not literally applicable.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Is your point just that this was the best tag to be used?